# Target only clicked anchor not siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function adding an `active` class  and also changing the text of the anchor when the class is added.

My issue is that I have multiple anchors of the same class and when I click one all of their texts change. I just want to target only the one I click on that has class `active`.

```js
function bindMoreInfoClickHandler() {
  $('.more-info').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.container-outer').toggleClass('active');

    if ($('.micro-accordion-container--outer').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.toggle-text').text('Less Info')
    } else {
      $('.toggle-text').text('More Info')
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to use DOM traversal instead of selecting all elements. We need to see the HTML to know how to traverse it to relate the clicked `.more-info` to the required `.toggle-text`

Comment: if `.toggle-text` is inside `.more-info`, then just change `$(".toggle-text")` to `$this.find(".toggle-text")`. but it would be helpful if you provide the relevant html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.toggle-text').text('Less Info')
```

The above line will select all of your `.toggle-text` elements. If `.toggle-text` is a child element of `.container-outer` you can do something like this:

```
$('.container-outer.active').find('.toggle-text').text('Less Info');
$('.container-outer:not(.active)').find('.toggle-text').text('More Info');
```

and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want ?

```js
$('.more-info').on('click', function() {
  $(".more-info").removeClass("active").html("More Info");
  $(this).addClass("active").html("Less Info");
});
```

```css
a{
display:block;
padding:10px;
background:#f5f5f5;
margin:10px;
}
.active{
  color:red;
{
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="more-info">More Info</a>
<a class="more-info">More Info</a>
<a class="more-info">More Info</a>
<a class="more-info">More Info</a>
```